# Praat Script "set boundaries over multiple tiers"

Tags: praat

I am wondering whether is there any script for aligning boundaries over multiple tiers. I set boundaries for one tier and I would like to set the same boundaries over multiple tiers, is there any Script for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This script will create two duplicate tiers for every text grid in a folder. To modify the arguments of the "Duplicate tier:" command to get exactly what you want, you can go to the following website, which is really useful when Praat scripting: http://www.bibiko.de/praat/wizard/

```
#Required parameters to get started.
form Enter the parameters to get started processing your data
  comment Directory of TextGrid files
    text textGrid_directory "enter directory path in quote"
endform

Create Strings as file list... list 'textGrid_directory$'*.TextGrid

numberOfFiles = Get number of strings
for ifile to numberOfFiles
    
    soundname$ = Get string... ifile
    Read from file... 'textGrid_directory$''soundname$'

    Duplicate tier: 1, 1, "Duplicate_one"
    Duplicate tier: 1, 1, "Duplicate_two"

    Save as text file... 'textGrid_directory$''soundname$'

    Remove

    select Strings list

endfor
```